# 3 column layout with dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I wanted to have a 3 column layout with dynamic width. Here is my scenario.

1. 3 divs inside a body element.
2. The width of all divs are marked as auto so that depending upon the content inside the divs
   the width of div has to grow so as the body element outside it.
3. Actually the content inside the divs mostly have placeholders which are fed with data from database and length of them increases dynamically.
4. The body should append with horizontal scroll bar if the width grows.

I tried floating the elements, displaying them `inline-block` and having `overflow-x: scroll/hidden`, but nothing worked for me. I feel i am missing something or doing it wrong.

Kindly help.

Comment: Share what you've already done so we can work from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set percentage widths. So 3 columns with `width:33%;` and `display:inline-block` should be enough. `position:relative;` and/or `overflow:hidden;` might be good for containing elements inside each column if your project requires it.

Note, 3 columns are a bit picky, so if 33% isn't perfect, try with decimals `33.333%`, another common trick is to float the last elm right like `.column:last-child{float:right}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Robert. But if I set width to 33% the content inside it cannot exceed more than that. Since iam providing overflow:hidden or if i apply clearfix hack the content is occupying the next line rather than increasing the div width horizontally

Comment: my bad, i forgot about your last point. In any case, when I need to do that I set the width with javascript so it forces it horiztonally. I've never really been able to come up with a comprehensive way to do this with just css but there are lots of examples out there, css tricks is always good: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/

Comment: Thanks Robert, this is useful